# Input not being fully contained by parent

Tags: html, css

I've got this search form: http://jsfiddle.net/1emsaoq1/2/

```
<div class="search_language">
    <div class="menu_search_container">
        <form action="/search">
            <input autocomplete="off" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }" id="search_field" name="q" placeholder="Rechercher..." type="text">
            <a href="#" class="icon-search"></a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result I'm trying to get is having the `input` vertically aligned inside the red `div`. When I inspect the `input` and parents, I can clearly see that it's parent is well vertically aligned inside the red `div` but not the `input`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the `#search_field` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tnLhxhj5/)

```
.menu_search_container form #search_field {
    /* other styles.. */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

By default, the `input` element's `display` is `inline-block`. In addition, the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`. Changing the value to `top` essentially corrects this behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your `line-height` into your `.search_langage`, set it to zero or take it off, and your problem will be fix.